# Is there completely free options broker?

Tags: stocks, options, trading, stock-markets, broker

I'm looking for cheapest options broker available, and stumbled across Firstrade.
They don't charge commission or fee, but unfortunately they collect SEC Fee and Options Regulatory Fee when selling or buying options https://www.firstrade.com/content/en-us/pricing.

So is there broker available which doesn't charge any fees even on behalf of SEC and ORF?
If not, is there any cheaper options broker?

Comment: Requests for product recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

All U.S. brokers must comply with SEC regulations.

Are you aware that as of  February 18, 2020, the SEC Fee rate is $22.10 for every $1,000,000 in sale proceeds?  It's listed at [your broker's web site](http://www.firstrade.com/content/en-us/pricing).  That amounts to about two cents for a $1,000 trade.